# Sorting date as 2nd criteria gives wrong order

Tags: sorting, libreoffice-calc

The date is in the correct format ie YYYY-MM-DD. If I sort just on date it sorts to correct order however if i sort on another field first with date the second criteria it is sorted correctly on first criteria but the date is sorted by DD first MM second and YYYY last. Out of curiosity I tried the same file in Excel which sorted correctly. Can anyone explain the difference and how to get a correct sort in Calc? Using 2 criteria in Calc does not work. I tried sorting on date first and species second. Date order was correct but species were jumbled.

The data is a spreadsheet download of an online data base where we record squirrel and other species sightings in the forest. The entries are not in date or species order. There are many fields for each entry but I am trying to sort first to species and then each species to be in date order. It is for an animation using Time Manager.

I have re-asked the question with edit because the question was closed, for what reason I don't know.

Comment: Not sure what you're using to sort them, but as a rule of thumb you will want to sort them by date and then by type as they will keep the date order when grouped into types.

Comment: The data is in a calc spreadsheet, I first define the range, Data - Sort.  I then select species as first Key and date as second key.  This results in a correct sort on species but the date is sorted incorrectly ie sorted by DD first MM second and YYYY last

Answer (score 0):

The sort does work correctly, tried again and all sorted as it should.  Tried to reproduce strange date order but can't.  Have no idea what went wrong originally.